# Should memory returned by MapViewOfFile() be marked as volatile?

Tags: c++, winapi

The title of the question says it all:

[`MapViewOfFile()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366761(v=vs.85).aspx) returns a `void*` (disguised as a `LPVOID`).

It seems to me that memory pointed by this pointer should be declared as volatile:

```
volatile void* ptr = MapViewOfFile(...);
```

Yet I couldn't find any such recommendation anywhere. Of course in practice everything works just fine without `volatile`...

What am I missing?

Comment: `volatile` only language/compile hint to prevent some optimization with variable. not related to `MapViewOfFile` at all. in general it absolute not need volatile here

Comment: `volatile` that memory gets actually read whenever the abstract C code performs a memory read and prevents the compiler from caching values (e.g. in registers). It seems completely relevant in this context.

Comment: Do you expect the contents of the file to change outside the process that mapped it? What coordination are you taking with the writing process?

Comment: "Do you expect the contents of the file to change outside the process that mapped it?" -> Yes, absolutely. "What coordination are you taking with the writing process?" -> I'm using local named mutexes (i.e. system-wide, at the session level).

Comment: in this case yes - if you by sense need `volatile` on memory, but this related to any shared memory (not only related to `MapViewOfFile`) - for example https://godbolt.org/g/L29Dr5 - compare code with https://godbolt.org/g/Hbgp1w

Comment: @RbMm Your code snippets just demonstrate the effect of `volatile`. They are unrelated to the question at hand.

Comment: answer depend not from how you get pointer to some memory (`MapViewOfFile` here unrelated) but from how you use it. need look in concrete code. in some (rarely i think) case volatile really need. in some not need. usual when we write to shared memory we use some synchronization. say do this in some "critical section". in this case `volatile` not need. but without your concrete code - impossible exactly say - need you use `volatile` or not

Comment: look also for this https://godbolt.org/g/93WQWv - add call some external function already suppress use cached value.

Comment: I suspect that this last example is very compiler specific. I wouldn't rely on this behavior. However your remark about synchronization got me thinking: they typically imply some kind of memory barrier, which I suspect forces the compiler to reload variables from memory? In which case volatile would indeed be superfluous.

Comment: not think. try on any another compiler - https://godbolt.org/g/euat45 and comment (//gn(); call for compare). need look for your concrete code. you of course can add any memory barries etc. but in most case this is absolute not need. need understand what we doing. and without exactly code example - impossible exactly say - need something here or not

Comment: Looking at the output of specific compilers or compiler versions is not that useful as it's only incidental. The behavior of C++ is precisely described nowadays (now that it has a well defined memory model) so we should be able to reason purely in terms of C++ semantics.

Comment: but again - need view concrete code for say exactly. you can all variables declare as volatile. set memory barriers between everything. and so what ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/176234/discussion-between-francois-beaune-and-rbmm).